# 405 Error when Trying to Create Task through Rest API

Tags: soql, rest-api, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, salesforcesdk

I am trying to create a Task object through a RestRequest in a Native Android App (RestRequest.getRequestForCreate).
The Problem is  that I am getting 405 error Method Not Allowed

What am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
        RestRequest request = RestRequest.getRequestForCreate(fragment.getActivity().getString(R.string.api_version), "Task", fields);

            client.sendAsync(request, new AsyncRequestCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(RestRequest request,
                        RestResponse response) {
                    System.out.println("OK");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(fragment.getActivity())
                    .setTitle("Error")
                    .setMessage("Bad Response")
                    .show();
                }
            });
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(fragment.getActivity())
            .setTitle("Error")
            .setMessage("Bad Response")
            .show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(fragment.getActivity())
            .setTitle("Error")
            .setMessage("No connection")
            .show();
        }
```

it says unexpected response code 405 for https://eu3.salesforce.com/services/data/31.0/sobjects/Task

Comment: post your code.

Comment: done. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you confirm that this is a create and not an update? `RestRequest.getRequestForUpsert` will handle both cases.

Comment: It is a create are you saying i can use the req for update ?

Comment: Tying to insert and supplying an ID results in an error in general; just wanted to make sure that you were clear that its an insert and it sounds like you are.

Comment: I suggest you use e.g. `setMessage("Bad Response: " + e)` on all your exception handlers to get any available detail about the 405.