# fields required to create a task through Rest API in native android app

Tags: soql, rest-api, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am getting error 405 when trying to create a new task through the rest api in a native android app
see

[405 Error when Trying to Create Task through Rest API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50611/405-error-when-trying-to-create-task-through-rest-api)

Now I am guessing it might depends on what paremeters i am setting which are:

```
   Subject
   Description
   ActivityDate
   CallDisposition
   CallDurationInSeconds
   CallType
   ReminderDateTime
   OwnerID (With the id of the logged user)
   WhoId (with the Id of a Contact or Lead)
   WhatId(with the Id of a contact or an Account, blank in case of a Lead
```

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the json body using in request.